# Cant get past SSL handShake on iOS simulator even after manual installing certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, ios-simulator, ssl-certificate

Summary: Struggling to get passed the SSL handshake on my iOS Simulator.

I am trying to get past the SSL handshake on my iOS simulator Xcode 7.2 simulator 9.2. I have pulled the .cer file from apps web page (URL) and manually installed in the simulator, but have not managed to get past the SSL handshake in the simulator.

Background information:

- The app was not built in Xcode, It is accessible via both desktop and via and app on the device.
- The apple device(not my simulator) have pre built corporate policies that give them access to the app.
- The desktops app only works if on the corporate wifi.
- I am launching the simulator via appium, and am manually inputing the login information on the app.

What I have attempted. (both were attempted when on corporate WIFI)

1. Drag and dropping The Certificate (from the apps URL) on to the simulator .. installing. Then going to the app and attempting sign in.
2. After dragging the Certificate and installing. I went to the apps URL in safari and I successfully managed to access it. However trying the app login after came up with the same SSL error.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Luke

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem getting my app to work with my SSL certificate and solved it in the following way:

1. Including the .cer file into the apps directory in xcode.
2. Use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and the following code for pinning and to complete SSL handshake

```swift
let hatchliCert = "nameOfCert"  
var urlSession: NSURLSession!
var serverTrustPolicy: ServerTrustPolicy!
var serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy]!
var afManager: Manager!



func configureAlamoFireSSLPinningWithCertificateData(certificateData: NSData) {
    print("entering alamo ssl pinning")
    let pathToCert = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(hatchliCert, ofType: "cer")
    let localCertificate:NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToCert!)!
    self.configureAlamoFireSSLPinningWithCertificateData(localCertificate)
    self.serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.PinCertificates(
        // Getting the certificate from the certificate data
        certificates: [SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certificateData)!],
        // Choose to validate the complete certificate chain, not only the certificate itself
        validateCertificateChain: true,
        // Check that the certificate matches the host who provided it
        validateHost: true
    )
    self.serverTrustPolicies = ["www.nameOfWebsite.com": self.serverTrustPolicy!]
    self.afManager = Manager(
        configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: self.serverTrustPolicies)
    )

}
```

This worked for me, but it seems like you have a slightly different situation with the corporate security. Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the program wasn't built in Xcode. I'm using appium and java to launch it and have no way of adding .cer file to the app.

Comment: If you have no ability to add the certificate into the app then I see no way it could ever initiate the handshake. I'm sure that appium has a way to include files into the directory where the app can recognize it.